# Send Photo Telegram API

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to send a photo using the [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot) library, but it's not working!

Here is my code:

```
private void btnSendImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api(token);

        Task<Telegram.Bot.Types.Update[]> res = Bot.GetUpdates();

        List<string> users = GetIds();
        foreach (var update in res.Result)
        {
            if (!users.Contains("" + update.Message.Chat.Id))
            {
                AddId("" + update.Message.Chat.Id);

            }
        }
        users = GetIds();
        foreach (var item in users)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {

                var rep = Bot.SendPhoto(Convert.ToInt32(item), txtImagePath.Text, txtMessage.Text);
            }
        }

    }
```

and `txtImagePath.text= "D:\Projects\Telegram Bot\Telegram Bot\bin\Debug\4.jpg";`

I tested it with `Bot.SendMessage` and it worked fine, but I can't send a photo!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz No, nothing happend!

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the `Bot.SendPhoto` in the loop and ensure it's getting hit and that the ID is valid?

Comment: @Jezzabeanz I do that and it hits. If I use Bot.sendMessage Its work fine!

Comment: Hmm, I'll build it myself and see if I can get it working. I can't help further at the moment until I get into the code myself I'm afraid. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz I can share my application with you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88260/discussion-between-jezzabeanz-and-sma6871).

Comment: Hi @sma6871 I've messaged you in chat. If you can open the above link you will see my message

Answer (score 7):

I used this code and it's worked!

```
var FileUrl = @"C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\20160201_204055.jpg";
using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(FileUrl, FileMode.Open))
        {
            FileToSend fts = new FileToSend();
            fts.Content = stream;
            fts.Filename = FileUrl.Split('\\').Last();
            var test = await bot.SendPhoto("@channel Name or chat_id", fts, "My Text");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Just for future reference of developers, the FileToSend is member of Telegram.Bot.Types name space

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass a Stream to the function if you want to send an new image.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(txtImagePath.Text, FileMode.Open))
{
    var rep = await Bot.SendPhoto(Convert.ToInt32(item), stream, txtMessage.Text);
}
```